# Updating to python3 from 2 TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Tags: python

When trying to upgrade a module from python 2 to using python 3 I am hitting type errors when trying to hash file data I am faced with the TypeError "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing" when I encode the data it then throws a TypeError "can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str"

```
    with open(realPath, "rb") as fn:
        while True:
            filedata = fn.read(self.piece_length)

            if len(filedata) == 0:
                break
            length += len(filedata)
            ##First error was here fixed with .decode()
            data += filedata.decode('utf-8')

            if len(data) >= self.piece_length:
                info_pieces += sha1(data[:self.piece_length]).digest()
                data = data[self.piece_length:]

            if check_md5:
                md5sum.update(filedata)
    if len(data) > 0:
        ##New error happens here
        info_pieces += sha1(data).digest()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hash functions work with `bytes`, not `str` now. So the object you pass to `sha1` should be `bytes`, and the return value of `.digest()` will also be `bytes`.

So you should encode the string `data` to bytes before passing to `sha1()`, like:

```
info_pieces += sha1(data[:self.piece_length].encode('utf-8')).digest()
```

Make sure you've initialized your variables like `data = ''` and `info_pieces = b''`, since `data` is decoded text and `info_pieces` contains the hash digests.

Answer (score 0):

`.digest()` returns a 'byte object', not a string.  You also need to `decode()` it, like:

`info_pieces += sha1(data).digest().decode('utf-8')`

or

`info_pieces += str(sha1(data).digest(), 'utf-8')`

Comment: I have tried doing it that way it just spits out the same "Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing"

Comment: oh sorry, I was answering the `when I encode the data it then throws a TypeError "can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str"` part.